# How to add PRISM modules to Toolbar using MEF and MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

I am using PRISM 4.0 with MEF as my container. I have defined 2 regions, ToolBar and MainRegion in my Shell. The toolbar region is automatically populated with my ToolBarModule using a custom RegionBehaviour - AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehaviour. My MainRegion can contain 1 or more View modules which will be docked via a third party dock layout manager.

I'm having trouble creating the toolbar buttons to represent the available views in my application. My idea was to use a ToolBarService or an Event pattern so that each View module could register itself with the ToolBar in a decoupled manner.

However it seems my View Module contructor is not called until I call RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion...

How can I control the initialisation of my modules so they can register with the ToolBar. Thus allowing them to add a button but not actually show the view itself. The View will only be shown when the button the view just registered is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't realised I should be doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I control the initialisation of my modules so they can
>   register with the ToolBar but not be shown initally?

I'm not sure what you mean by that.

I understand that you want modules to register it's own navigation part when they loaded. I have similar scenario where I have menu bar on top and button bar below. Each module when loaded - inserts it's own buttons/menus using Initialize code:

```
public void Initialize()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.Menu, typeof(NavigationView));
            this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.Toolbar, typeof(ToolbarNavigationView));
        }
```

Those regions have actual buttons/items which when pressed call something else. For examle, here is `NavigationViewModel`

```
namespace IDATT.Module.SystemManager.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

    using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;

    [Export]
    public class NavigationViewModel
    {
        [Import]
        public ISecurityService SecurityService { get; set; }

        [Import]
        public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

        public void Mail()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Tabs, new Uri(typeof(MailView).Name, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void MaintainUser()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Tabs, new Uri(typeof(MaintainUserView).Name, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void MaintainGroup()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Tabs, new Uri(typeof(MaintainGroupView).Name, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void MaintainMailTemplate()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Tabs, new Uri(typeof(MaintainMailTemplateView).Name, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void SetUpOptions()
        {
            this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.Tabs, new Uri(typeof(SetUpSystemManagerOptionsView).Name, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            this.SecurityService.Logout();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Katit, thanks for your help. I will re-word my question to be a bit clearer. Essentially what I am creating is an empty application, I don't know what buttons and views will be available. This will be for the users of my framework to decide. What I need to do is give them a way to add a button to the toolbar. When this button is clicked the view will load. It seems like my view modules constructor is not called until I call RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion... I want to better control the lifecycle of my view modules. Hope that makes it clearer. Thankss

Comment: It's still a bit unclear why buttons will "magically" appear? If you let users choose what will be available than use those settings when you write code to `RegisterViewWithRegion` and display those appropriate buttons.

Comment: Hi Katit, what I am writing is a generic framework that contains a toolbar region and a main region. Content users will then take this framework and write their own view modules. The main region can host several view modules at the same time and these can be docked in various configurations. What I needed to expose was a way for the content users to create buttons on the toolbar that can launch there view modules. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way but it seems to work now with a custom region behaviour. Without that my constructor would not be called.

Comment: I think you overthinking or overdoing this. Your users (whoever writing modules) will go by convention. You tell them region name where they need to place buttons and they do it via `RegisterViewWithRegion` when their module initializes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can "force" the constructor of my view module to be called by using a custom RegionBehaviour. Inside of this I can cast my view module to a specific base view or interface type and call the a function. This will then register my view with the toolbar but not necessarily show the view in the "main" region of my application.

Thanks for your help.